# iPhone: Existence of a Memory Leak Profiler?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Is there such a thing as a Memory profiler for Iphones apps?

I'd like to know what objects are in memory at any moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use Instruments to profile your App. You can run your app with different templates.

In XCode, select **Run > Start With Performance Tool > Object Allocations**

Answer (score 3):

Shark is a memory profiler that comes with the Apple Developer Tools, it can be used with both iPhone and Mac applications. See: [Shark User Guide (iPhone)](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SharkUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, I think Apple is phasing out Shark in favor of Instruments. Instruments provides memory profiling tools (allocated objects, leaks, etc...) and can connect to the iPhone Simulator or a remote device to profile iPhone apps. I've never tried to use it to show the actual objects in memory though - just allocation/deallocation activity.

Comment: Not really phasing out - they cover slightly different scopes.  That being said, Instruments is much more apt for this task than Shark is.