# iPhone Application universal app

Tags: iphone

I am working on one application and in which I am downloading 2000 images and store some data in SQlite database using connection from server.This works fine in simulator but crash in iPhone device.I am using try..catch for handel error but it simply crash and not display any error.So please help me to run this application in device also.

Comment: You're probably crashing due to low memory. Have you used Instruments to check your memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an app in which i used to download more than 600 images n each of the image was about 700kb and more, the app was working perfect in the simulator but the performace was poor in the device. As the App was for IOS3, Shark tool helped me out, and the only reason was leakage of memory which i had never expected. To my knowledge, the reason of memory leakage must be the main reason. And do try to have a deep look on how the things are working in the main thread, try to run most og the things in backend.

Regards,
Suhail

Comment: Shark doesn't have anything to do with memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

But i can help you out for showing the processes taking place in the main thread. and if i am not wrong do go through this post [iPhone: Existence of a Memory Leak Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099437/iphone-existence-of-a-memory-leak-profiler)

Comment: But their is no memory leakage when i run it in simulator.I also run application using profile zombises and their is no memory leakage showen in it.